# What can I do with a large amount of glacé cherries?

Tags: culinary-uses, candy, cherries

I accidentally bought 1 kg of glacé cherries instead of the dried cherries which I meant to buy.

Aside from fruitcake, which I hate, is there anything I can do to use these up?

Answer (score 4):

If you search for *glacé cherries* you're going to get nowhere; these are much more commonly referred to as *candied cherries* and there are [plenty of recipes](http://allrecipes.com/Search/Ingredients.aspx?WithTerm=&SearchIn=All&Wanted1=candied%20cherries) to be found.

More specifically, the most common pairing seems to be almonds. Seems you can make just about any confection from almonds and candied cherries: cookies, nut brittle, bourbon/almond balls, cookies/biscotti, quickbreads, and even fudge.

Answer (score 1):

Top cookies with them before baking.
Chop and make ice box cookies.
Add to a pound cake.
Add to brownies or fudge.
Mix them into ice cream (chocolate, vanilla, or cherry flavoured).
Chop and mix with coconut and sweetened condensed milk to make confections. (No bake.)
Even if you cannot used them up quickly, they last forever in a tightly sealed mason jar on the shelf at room temperature.

Answer (score 0):

Soak them in kirsch and make and inauthentic Black Forest Cake?

Cover them in chocolate?

Put them in sweet mixed drinks?  (hard to use up 1kg that way, I know)

Otherwise you're pretty much stuck with fruitcake.  You don't have to make a brick, though; you can make the good kinds of fruitcake, like panettone or stollen.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used glacé cherries, so I'm not sure how these would come out, but perhaps you can use them to make the following:

- Cherries jubilee
- Chutney
- Clafoutis
- Roast duck with cherry gastrique
- Tart of pasty cream and cherries poached with cinnamon

Answer (score 0):

You could make them into a form of wine? or depending on how artificial they are you could use them to flavor some vodka.

If you like confectionary you could soak them in a citric acid syrup to get rid of their cloying sweetness, then soak them in some booze and finally dip them in some dark chocolate.

Hope this gives you some inspiration!